# Alternative to UISplitViewController without need for it to be rootViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, uisplitview

I was wondering, I need some simple feature like a UISplitViewController where i have a master-detail navigation. I can't use a UISplitViewController as it requires to be associated as root view controller. I need to have this called modally within a View.

is there any similar alternative controller to implement this?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [MGSplitViewController](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=mgsplitviewcontroller&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFsQFjAA&url=http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad/&ei=8Ya2T5y4LMLtsgbS-sW3CA&usg=AFQjCNFmmXmDmaL7O_J8b3DMegPK57RfcA&sig2=92KdsQojF-kZASRher_nzg). Really good, offers similar API.